# Searching for only single words in Unix

Tags: awk, grep

Is there any way to cat a file that has something like:

```
field1,field2,field number 3,field4,field5

field1,field2,field3,field4,field5
```

(Some fields have spaces, some fields do not)

I want to print using `awk` $1 and $3, but only lines that do not have a space in field 3.
I don't know if there is any way to make awk print something only if it starts with , and ends with ,

Comment: Do any of the existing answers solve your problem? Please consider Accepting it, if so, using the checkmark next to it. Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

```
awk -F, '$3 !~ / / {print $1,$3}' input-file
```

Answer (score 3):

Lines don't have the space in Field 3

```
awk -F, '{n=split($3,a," ");if(n==1){print $1,$3}}' filename
```

Answer (score 2):

```
perl -F, -lane '$F[2] =~ /\s/ || print "@F[0,2]"' yourfile

sed -ne 's/^\([^,]*\),[^,]*,\([^ ,]*\)\(,.*\)\{0,\}$/\1 \2/p' yourfile

while IFS=, read -r f1 x f3 x; do case $f3 in *" "* ) : ;; * ) echo "$f1 $f3" ;; esac; done < yourfile
```